# Can't figure out how to apply tags on Main

Tags: support

I am brand new to Stack Exchange.

I think I am being particularly thick & dense.. I just can’t work out how to ‘Apply a Tag’ to my question on The English Language & Usage Site? I did (somehow!) manage it yesterday, my first post & question; however can’t for-the-life-of me, remember how I did it & can’t seem to replicate it today!

I have gone into the ‘help page’ and ‘’advanced help’ on Tags but STILL can’t ‘get it’! As well as taking ‘The Tour’ several times! Could you please, give me detailed and clear instructions how I can submit a tag to a further/additional question please?

When responding please note; I am severely dyslexic (think this is also the problem why I can’t fathom-out how to place a tag into a question) Therefore please make your explanation as clear and precise & detailed as possible.  Once I’ve ‘got it’; I won’t need to EVER ask again. Sorry to be a nuisance and pest.

I am able to use ‘the Tags’ on Meta; as I just simply ‘click’ on the blank space (in Tags) and I am given several options; in this particular instance, I chose ‘support’!! However I am unable to do this on the main Stack Exchange site! Maybe Stack Exchange, is just too advanced a site for me? Hope not!

Look forward to hearing back form you. How will I know if you have repsoned?  Thnak you in advance. Kind regards and best wishes (Thick and Dibby and confused!) Corinne

Answer (score 6):

### How tagging works

When you edit a question, there are three fields to fill out. In order from the top of the screen to the bottom, these are:

- title
- body
- **tags**

So, tags are the bottom-most text field which appears when you ask or edit a question. It is this field, outlined in red in the screenshot below, which you need to populate to properly tag your question.

[image: screenshot of "ask a question" form, with fields specific to tagging called out]

The user experience for this field can be a little confusing; it looks like a standard text input just like the title field, but when you start using it, it acts differently.

To use it, start typing the name of the tag you want (e.g. [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) or [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)), and below the field a list of tag suggestions will appear. Notice in the screenshot I've already included the badge "word choice", and then started typing `gr`, and the prompt below has dutifully suggested all tags containing that sequence of letters ("**gr**ammar", "**gr**ammaticality", "ortho**gr**aphy", etc).

You can click on one of the suggested tags to add it to your question, or simply finish typing the name of the tag. It's really best practice to re-use an existing tag than create your own (see *guidelines for tagging* outlined in purple).

You may add up to 5 tags per question.  However, it rarely necessary to add that many; usually one or two will suffice.  The ten most common tags on EL&U are:

1. [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning)
2. [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)
3. [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice)
4. [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)
5. [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology)
6. [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality)
7. [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases)
8. [expressions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions)
9. [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage)
10. [verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs)

You may click on any of those links to learn more about that specific tag, including the kind of questions it's usually applied to, or see a longer and more detailed [list of the most popular tags on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) (accessible by clicking the `tag` tab at the top of the list of questions).

### Notification of responses

In re: how to know if/when someone has responded to you: most people simply check back periodically or keep the site open in a background tab.

If someone has answered your question, addressed you in a comment, or voted on one of your posts, the black header bar at the top of the page will contain a notification (a red numeral, like an iOS badge, over the "inbox" icon for answers and comments; or a green highlight to the histogram icon for votes and other notifications relevant to your reputation).

Alternatively, if you have a mobile device, you can install the native app, and get push notifications and badges (similar to how you're notified of emails and txt messages).

Comment: Good answer! It's worth noting explicitly the difference between *grammar* and *grammaticality*. The latter is asking about whether something in particular is right; on the other hand *grammar* is more abstract and is asking about **why** a particular way of expressing something is right (that is, it's asking about the grammar itself, not the results of applying the grammar). The [grammar] tag appears in the top 10 because this difference is not completely understood. It should be **way** down the list!

Comment: I don't hang out in the gram*-tags much, but wouldn't asking whether something *is* grammatical necessarily entail an explanation of *why* it is grammatical? I mean, if not, then answers would consist of a bald "yep, it sure is!" or "no, that's totally wrong".

Comment: @DanBron Hello Dan Many thanks for this.. That was an amazingly clear & detailed explanation. You went to a great deal of trouble to illustrate and get the point across. .. It was extremely comprehensive. I have now fully understood how to use tags.

Comment: @CORINNE No problem. That's what we're here for. Welcome to EL&U! Looking forward to seeing you around.

Comment: @DanBron previous message too long to additionally add this
Dan, would/could you please, additionally inform me; why this question got edited? I would like to know, so I can understand more fully, in future, how I should post my questions.. (I seem to have a lot to learn about the workings and etiquette of Stack Exchange..  
I am most grateful to you for the time you took so I could fully comprehend ‘Tags’..
Enjoy your day
Kind regards and best wishes
Corinne

Comment: @CORINNE I was the one who edited your question. I made two changes: the big one was simply breaking up the body or your question into paragraphs, so it was easier to read and when a user initially opened it he wasn't presented with an unbroken "wall of text". I also shortened the title (using some local jargon) so it would fit into the list of questions better (i.e. make it easier for the locals here to immediately grasp what you were asking about, and therefore drive more attention to your question). FYI, if you're ever unhappy with any edits, as post-author, you can roll them back.

Comment: @DanBron Hello again Dan.. Oh I see.. I think I have an awful lot to learn and grasp as to the ‘ins and outs’ of the workings of Stack Exchange.. I will continue to persevere & hope (and pray) I get it right.. Eventually!.. Thanks again for your clear and concise explanation. Enjoy your day. Corinne